# Assign variable value to a block in jade

Tags: node.js, variables, block, pug, template-engine

Is it possible to assign the value of a variable to a block? Either it is not possible or I'm doing it wrong.

Example:

```
- var $foo = "bar"

block #{$foo}
    div.a_class Some content
```

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically assign variable to block?

Comment: Because I generated some blocks of html dynamically. I want these to contain blocks which I could overwrite or prepend/append from within another jade file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because blocks are compile-time, not runtime.